# pandas: remove dot only if it occurs after a digit in a string

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a datframe that looks like the following:

```
df=  pd.DataFrame(["I", "have", "5.", "apples", "."]
                 columns=['words'])
```

and I only want the dot following the number to be removed and not the dot at the end of the sentence. (5. --> 5)

I tried

`df["Words"].str.replace("\d.", "\d", regex=True)`

but it sends an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work - we need to use a capturing group in the regex so we know what value should replace the initial value. In addition, we need to use a raw-string literal to escape the backslashes in the regex string.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(["I", "have", "5.", "apples", "."],
                  columns=['words'])
>>> df["words"].str.replace(r"(\d)\.", r"\1")
0         I
1      have
2         5
3    apples
4         .
Name: words, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

We need

```
df["words"].str.replace(r"^(\d+)\.$", r"\1")
```

This matches longer digits as well and makes sure the last character is a dot instead of anything.

The answer of CDJB is not entirely correct:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["I", "have", "50a", "apples", "."],
                  columns=['words'])
[ins] In [12]: df["words"].str.replace(r"(\d).", r"\1")
Out[12]:
0         I
1      have
2        5a
3    apples
4         .
Name: words, dtype: object
```